# A sum of powers formula? (I was just playing around, I don't know if this is correct)

Tags: summation

So for reference, I'm just a high school student, who doesn't know that much maths stuff. But I noticed a pattern in binary numbers where, if you have all ones that is one less than if you have the next value (e.g. $1111$ is $1$ less than $10000$ - by definition). I generalised this to be a sum of base $2$ to $n$, and created a very simple sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k = 2^{n+1} - 1$$
This was pretty simple, and was pretty obvious. I tried generalising and came up with the thing below:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} a^k = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$

I'm not sure if this thing is actually correct, as I was just playing around. If it is correct can someone forward me to the offical proof.

Thanks

Comment: It is correct. Denote the sum on the left by $S$ and see what is $aS-S$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: Good work! This is a classic formula in mathematics known as a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Linked is the corresponding wiki page which includes a proof. Nice job deriving it.

Comment: Well done ! Good work and $\to +1$

Comment: Try computing $$\begin{align} (a-1)\sum_{k=0}^na^k &=\sum_{k=0}^na^{k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^na^k\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a^k-\sum_{k=0}^na^k\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You are correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series)! Well done!

For additional practice, I would encourage you strongly to try and *prove* the equality you found, before looking it up online.

There are two ways of proving the statement. Traditionally, one would define $$S=\sum_{k=0}^n a^k$$ and then observe the value of $$aS - S.$$

However, based on your reasoning, I would advise you look at what the sum looks like in base $a$. What does $a^n$ look like in base $a$?

Comment: Thanks. I will try to prove it, though I'm not sure how to write a proper proof. I'll see how I go I guess.

Comment: @PixelFireblade I edited my answer, take a look at my hint.